# How to create a percentage that is the sum of a quantity under many conditions

Tags: powerbi

I didn't know how to search for this question, apologies in advance if it was already answered.

I have a table with some batches, and each batch belongs to a product, and for each batch, whether the quality test failed or passed, and the quantity of products in this batch.

What I want to do is to create a percentage of the failed batches, but I can't seem to know how to do it.

I already have a matrix that displays for each product, the total of failed and passed quantities along with their total, so all I want to do is have another column next to it that displays the percentage of failed products.

Answer (score 0):

This cant be done column wise. You have to add a few measures. This example should help you figure out how to do it in your case (because you didnt post any sample data):

[image]

I used this 3 measures:

```
Count Failed = CALCULATE(COUNT('Table'[Column2]); FILTER('Table'; 'Table'[Column2] = "Failed"))

Total = COUNTROWS('Table')

Percentage = [Count Failed] / [Total]
```

Comment: Sorry for not posting any sample data as I cannot share any. The problem is that I don't want a count of failed, I want to check the quantity as each batch contain a different quantity and that's what I would like to count

Comment: Hmm... I dont really get what you mean. Try posting a minimal fictional sample of your data and what you want to archive. That would help.